# How to decompose linear regression error in statsmodel

Tags: linear-regression, statsmodels, data-fitting, decomposition

I want to decompose the error sum of the squares into the lack of fit error and pure error. I am using the `statsmodel` library.

```
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
res= model.fit()
```

I know how to decompose the total sum of squares(res.centered_tss) into the regression(res.ssr) and residual error(res.ess).

But I want to decompose it into pure error and lack of fit. My data has multiple y values for each x value so it is perfect for this type of analysis. How can I do this in `statsmodel`.

[Formula](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/d0c7108550c774fbe955cdeb1908eeccfdb01054)  of what I am looking for.